# Efficiently Managing Related Data in MongoDB: References vs Embedded Documents

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I'm developing an application using MongoDB and I'm facing a design decision regarding the best way to structure my data for users and their interests. I currently have two collections: users and interests. Each user document includes an interestedIn array containing the _ids of interests from the interests collection, like so:

```
{

"name":"dummy name",
"age":19,
"email":"dummy@dummy.com",
"intrestedIn":\[
"620481a3e0afaa0023419cb1",
"620481a3e0afaa0023419cb1",
"620481a3e0afaa0023419cb1"
]
}
```

I want to output user data along with the details of their interests. Ideally, the output should look like this:

```
{
"name":"dummy name",
"age":19,
"email":"dummy@dummy.com",
"intrestedIn":[
{"icon":football.png,"title":football},
{"icon":basketball.png,"title":basketball},
{"icon":cricket.png,"title":cricket},
]

}
```

I've considered using aggregation to fetch interest details by _id from the interests collection, but I'm concerned about the scalability and efficiency of this approach, especially if interests are frequently accessed or updated.

Another consideration is if an admin updates an interest (e.g., changes the icon or title), how would I efficiently update this information in each user's document if the interest details were embedded?